# <Method> is not supported by the language

Tags: c#

I am writing an orchestration (restful web) service that will broker the calls to multiple dependent services and package up the results into a single comprehensive result object.

Part of this is mapping the inputs and outputs of the various services into the inputs to the other services.

For example, `OrchestrationService` takes in an input.  It calls `DepServiceA` to retrieve a result.   It then takes the output of `DepServiceA`, combines it with the input to `OrchestrationService` to produce the input to `DepServiceB`.  `DepServiceB` returns a result that is then combined with the result of `DepServiceA` and the input to `OrchestrationService` to create the inputs to `DepServiceC` and `DepServiceD`.  All of this mapping is done via a cohesive mapper class - `Mapper`.

Now for the rub.  There are two similar, but distinct endpoints in `OrchestrationService` that take in two similar, but distinct inputs, and call two similar, but distinct calls to `DepServiceB`.  *The rest of the workflow is identical*.  The only difference is the inputs to `DepServiceB`.

So, I abstracted out the common parts of `Mapper` into `MapperBase`, an abstract class, and two subclasses `Mapper1` and `Mapper2`.

The basic idea is this.

```
public abstract class MapperBase {
    protected ServiceCInput MapToServiceCInput(ServiceBOutput output, [some other fields passed in from subclass state]){
        //map to Service C Input
    }

    protected ServiceDInput MapToServiceDInput(ServiceBOutput output, [some other fields passed in from subclass state]){
        //map to Service D Input
    }

    public abstract ServiceCInput MapToServiceCInput(ServiceBOutput output);
    public abstract ServiceDInput MapToServiceDInput(ServiceBOutput output);
}

public class Mapper1 : MapperBase {
    public ServiceCInput MapToServiceCInput(ServiceBOutput output){
        return MapToServiceCInput(output, [state based params]);
    }
    public ServiceDInput MapToServiceDInput(ServiceBOutput output){
        return MapToServiceDInput(output, [state based params]);
    }

    public ServiceBInput1 MapToServiceBInput(ServiceAOutput serviceAOutput){
        //map to Service B Input 1
    }
}

public class Mapper2 : MapperBase {
    public ServiceCInput MapToServiceCInput(ServiceBOutput output){
        return MapToServiceCInput(output, [state based params]);
    }
    public ServiceDInput MapToServiceDInput(ServiceBOutput output){
        return MapToServiceDInput(output, [state based params]);
    }

    public ServiceBInput2 MapToServiceBInput(ServiceAOutput serviceAOutput){
        //map to Service B Input 2
    }
}
```

Now, these mappers are used in the actual endpoints, no problem.

However, because I'm a good developer, I want to ensure that these mappers conform to my specifications, and have unit tests to cover that.

`Mapper1` has zero problems.  The unit tests compile and run.

`Mapper2` has a similar set of unit tests.  However, `Mapper2`'s set generates the following compile error:

`'MapToServiceBInput' is not supported by the language`.

This occurs *only* in the unit tests project, and *only* for `Mapper2`.  It doesn't matter what I name the method.  It always generates this error (with whatever name the method currently has).  No other method on either class has an issue.  Just this one.

I've tried the following:

- removing the reference to the endpoint project and readding it
- cleaning the solution (and manually deleting the bin/obj directories across the entire solution
- renaming the method.
- removing the inheritance to the base class
- rebooting my machine
- placing the call in a different file in the unit tests project
- all combinations of the above.

I *always* get this compiler error, but only for `Mapper2` and only for the unit tests project.

I'm at a loss.

Comment: Check the .NET version specified in each project, see if you're using different versions.

Comment: Good idea.  Close, but not exactly.   I did just figure it out.  Each service publishes it's own version of it's own contracts.  My endpoint was pointed at a version that contained the contracts for ServiceB which had ServiceBInput2.  However, my Unit Tests project was somehow pointed to a different version, that did _not_ contain this reference.

Comment: Make sure your references are *project* references, and not *build output* references. If in doubt, remove a reference and re-add it, making sure you pick it from the projects list and not by browsing to a "matching" assembly on disk. Such badly created references will not be picked up by Visual Studio as a build order dependency and then projects will be built out of order, which means when project B is built, it uses an old version of project A, simply because Visual Studio did not understand that project A had to be built first.

Comment: Well, the only project reference here is the Endpoint Project is referenced directly by the Unit Test project.   GENERALLY, the Service contracts are pulled in via nuget.  However, the published nuget package did not contain the contracts I needed.  So I referenced it on disk (file browse reference, it's in a different solution) to be unblocked.  However, I neglected to update the unit tests project,.

Comment: As a result, they referenced different versions of the contracts.